# ServiceLoader load - duplicate class which loads first?

Tags: java

When using ServiceLoader.load(X.class) and there are 2 jar files which contain definitions for X.class which one will get deployed?

The issue I'm seeing is that this appears to be intermittent in terms of class load order.

This is a issue as the definitions are slightly different.

Ideally this would only appear once on the class path and avoid all problems but in the intermediate time I'm trying to understand whats loads first.

Comment: As for my understanding all classes found get loaded in the order they appear in the classpath. But since the API does not specify this it is uncertain. and even if it is true it may change with later Java versions.

Comment: It depends on the order in which the service loader definition files for the interface appear on the CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on java version, application server type and version, probably even file system settings and who knows what else.
I think it's enough to say that there is no guarantee about the order, and it's something you should never rely on.

Answer (score 2):

For javadoc of ServiceLoader#load(Class):

> Creates a new service loader for the given service type, using the current thread's context class loader.
> An invocation of this convenience method of the form
> ServiceLoader.load(service)
> is equivalent to
> ServiceLoader.load(service, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader())

For Javadoc of ServiceLoader#load(Class, ClassLoader):

> Ordering: The service loader will first locate any service providers in modules defined to the class loader, then its parent class loader, its parent parent, and so on to the bootstrap class loader. If a class loader has modules in a module layer then all providers in that module layer are located (irrespective of their class loader) before the providers in the parent class loader are located. The ordering of modules in same class loader, or the ordering of modules in a module layer, is not defined.